# Can we combine SVG Overlay with MarkerCluster v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3, markers

I have searched here and there on how to prevent the overlapping circle (svg) layer created from json file. Poor me, no luck till now. Since I doesn't know how to prevent the overlapping circle I thought of using the MarkerCluster. The question is can we combine SVG Overlay on Google Map with MarkerCluster v3? The circle will be placed based on coordinate stored in the json file.